# Why Java do not support sorted by value?

Tags: java, data-structures

I have a question such as the title write. I want know why?

the scene is, if i have a map, the key means an id, value means score.

so, First, i want to sorted the map by score. Second, i want to get top n (may be 10) elements after sorted.

i find a way to implement what i think. but i'm be confused with **why map do not support sorted by value?**

When I use Java, I write this code to sorted a `HashMap`:

```
public class SortedMapTest {


    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Map<Long, Double> scoreMap = new HashMap<>();
        scoreMap.put(100L, 3.0);
        scoreMap.put(22L, 2.4);
        scoreMap.put(45L, 2.0);

        Map<Long, Double> sortedMap = new TreeMap<>(new ValueCompare(scoreMap));

        sortedMap.putAll(scoreMap);

        System.out.println(sortedMap);

    }

    static final class ValueCompare implements Comparator<Long> {

        private Map<Long, Double> map;

        public ValueCompare(Map<Long, Double> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        @Override
        public int compare(Long o1, Long o2) {
            Double d1 = map.get(o1);
            Double d2 = map.get(o2);
            return d2.compareTo(d1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You forgot to ask.

Comment: What's the expected output? What's the actual output?

Comment: You have posted code here yourself that sorts by value; why are you saying that Java can't sort by value?

Comment: sorry, this is my first time to ask an question on stackoverflow. i will take care of this thanks a lot

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt, i don't mean java can't sort by value. the way i sorts a map,it's trick. in my opinion i think there must better way to do this. in other words, java do not support native way to sort a map? it that correct?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not a limitation of Java, but of the specific map implementation you chose, which is a `TreeMap`. The way this class works is that the sort order of an entry cannot change just because the entry's value is updated.

Further note that map values are generally not required to be immutable, so the sort order could actually change at any time without the map getting to know about it. This is why it is generally considered bad design to even attempt implementing such a structure.

There are other options to meet your original requirement, which do not involve maps automatically sorted on the entry value. The choice of the best option will depend on the details of that requirmeent which you did not post.

Comment: can you tell me some other way to get a sorted map or sorted the map by given map?